# How to create a seating chart in angularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, laravel

I want to create a seating chart in angularJS. I could follow this [idea](http://paulhammant.com/2012/03/03/replacing-jquery-with-angular/) but I need an admin to be able to move the tables and seats around, resize them and remove them as they wish. Also it's an office seating chart with different offices that have different layouts. Anyone who has an idea of how I could implement this? I am using Laravel for the backend.

Comment: Were you able to implement this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not go with SVG ?

- Main frame is your office/room floor
- js/jquery libraries to manipulate the shapes.
- Save shape points/size to db for later display

Then when displayed to client you can trigger events on shape clicks and handle the selection as you like

Comment: I need to implement similar thing in Vue.js. Can you help me more with your answer ?